# Unbound local error does not occur consistently

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup, geopy

I am trying to add data to my SQlite3 table which runs on a function that takes two arguments to find a city and a neighbourhood `def scrapecafes(city, area)` Strangely, this works well with some of the arguments I am entering but not with others. For example if I run `scrapecafes(melbourne, thornbury)` the code works fine, but if I run `scrapecafes(melbourne, carlton` I get the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lat' referenced before assignment`

I know the function definitely works, but I can't figure out why I am getting the UnboundLocalError for some arguments but not for others. Here is the code:

```
import folium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests import get
import sqlite3
import geopandas
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

#cafeNames
def scrapecafes(city, area):

    #url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    url = f"https://www.broadsheet.com.au/{city}/guides/best-cafes-{area}"
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNamesClean = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames] #clean the elements
    #cafeNameTuple = [(cafe,) for cafe in cafeNamesCleans

    #print(cafeNamesClean)

    #addresses
    soup_cafe_addresses = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_addresses)

    cafeAddresses = soup_cafe_addresses.findAll( attrs={"class":"address-content" })
    cafeAddressesClean = [address.text for address in cafeAddresses]
    #cafeAddressesTuple = [(address,) for address in cafeAddressesClean]

    #print(cafeAddressesClean)

    ##geocode addresses
    locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
    geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

    try:
        location = []
        for item in cafeAddressesClean:
            location.append(locator.geocode(item))

            lat = [loc.latitude for loc in location]
            long = [loc.longitude for loc in location]
    except:
        pass


    #zip up for table
    fortable = list(zip(cafeNamesClean, cafeAddressesClean, lat, long))
    print(fortable)
    
##connect to database
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('25july_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Database created and Successfully Connected to 25july_database")

        sqlite_select_Query = "select sqlite_version();"
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        print("SQLite Database Version is: ", record)
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while connecting to sqlite", error)

    #create table
    try:
        sqlite_create_table_query = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test555 (
                                        name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        address TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
                                        longitude FLOAT NOT NULL
                                        );'''

        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
        cursor.execute(sqlite_create_table_query)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("SQLite table created")

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while creating a sqlite table", error)

##enter data into table
    try:
        sqlite_insert_name_param = """INSERT INTO test555
                            (name, address, latitude, longitude)
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?);"""

        cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_name_param, fortable)

        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Total", cursor.rowcount, "Records inserted successfully into table")
        sqliteConnection.commit()

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)

    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `geopy` doesn't have co-ordinates for `Carlton`. Hence, you should change your table schema and insert `null` in those cases.

When `geopy` doesn't have data, it returns `None` and when try to call something on `None` it throws exception. You have to put the `try/except` block inside the `for` loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests import get
import sqlite3
import geopandas
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

#cafeNames
def scrapecafes(city, area):

    #url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    url = f"https://www.broadsheet.com.au/{city}/guides/best-cafes-{area}"
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNamesClean = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames] #clean the elements
    #cafeNameTuple = [(cafe,) for cafe in cafeNamesCleans

    #addresses
    soup_cafe_addresses = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    cafeAddresses = soup_cafe_addresses.findAll( attrs={"class":"address-content" })
    cafeAddressesClean = [address.text for address in cafeAddresses]
    #cafeAddressesTuple = [(address,) for address in cafeAddressesClean]

    ##geocode addresses
    locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
    geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
    lat = []
    long = []
    
    for item in cafeAddressesClean:
        try:
            location = locator.geocode(item.strip().replace(',',''))
            lat.append(location.latitude)
            long.append(location.longitude)
        except:
            lat.append(None)
            long.append(None)

    #zip up for table
    fortable = list(zip(cafeNamesClean, cafeAddressesClean, lat, long))
    print(fortable)
    
##connect to database
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('25july_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Database created and Successfully Connected to 25july_database")

        sqlite_select_Query = "select sqlite_version();"
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        print("SQLite Database Version is: ", record)
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while connecting to sqlite", error)

    #create table
    try:
        sqlite_create_table_query = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
                                        name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        address TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        latitude FLOAT,
                                        longitude FLOAT
                                        );'''

        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
        cursor.execute(sqlite_create_table_query)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("SQLite table created")

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while creating a sqlite table", error)

##enter data into table
    try:
        sqlite_insert_name_param = """INSERT INTO test
                            (name, address, latitude, longitude)
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?);"""

        cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_name_param, fortable)

        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Total", cursor.rowcount, "Records inserted successfully into table")
        sqliteConnection.commit()

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)

    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")

scrapecafes('melbourne', 'carlton')
```